# upsample time while keeping original points values in python

Tags: python, signals, sampling, resampling

I have an unevenly spaced time sereies of arbitrary size (for example 7), see below, which i would like to upsample (50) and retain the original points.

```
ls = ['2016-01-30 12:10:00', 
  '2016-01-30 12:23:35', 
  '2016-01-30 12:24:14', 
  '2016-01-30 12:24:51', 
  '2016-01-30 12:25:00', 
  '2016-01-30 12:26:49', 
  '2016-01-30 12:27:36']
```

It basically doesn't matter in between which points the new time stamps are stored but preferably according time gap. So the bigger the time gap, the more new generated timestamps e.g.

```
new_ls = ['2016-01-30 12:10:00',
      x,
      x,
      x,
      x,
  '2016-01-30 12:23:35',
      x,
      x,
  '2016-01-30 12:24:14',
  '2016-01-30 12:24:51',
  '2016-01-30 12:25:00',
      x,
  '2016-01-30 12:26:49',
  '2016-01-30 12:27:36']
```

the resulting list can also be unevenly spaced.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by converting your list to `pd.DatetimeIndex` and finding the ideal distribution of time stamps between start and end:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ls = pd.to_datetime(['2016-01-30 12:10:00', 
                     '2016-01-30 12:23:35', 
                     '2016-01-30 12:24:14', 
                     '2016-01-30 12:24:51', 
                     '2016-01-30 12:25:00', 
                     '2016-01-30 12:26:49', 
                     '2016-01-30 12:27:36'])

n = 50
dt = (ls.max() - ls.min())/n
ls_temp = pd.date_range(start=ls.min(), end=ls.max(), freq=dt)
```

Then find out where to put the original measurements, for example by replacing the entry with the smallest absolute difference:

```
idx = np.abs(ls[:,None] - ls_temp[None, :]).argmin(axis=1)
ls_temp = pd.Series(ls_temp)
ls_temp[idx] = pd.Series(ls)
```

Note that this strategy might fail in some edge cases (where one index is being replaced by two values or something like that).

At the end, you can convert it back to your format for example with:

```
ls = list(map("{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}".format, ls_temp.tolist()))
```

Output:

```
['2016-01-30 12:10:00',
 '2016-01-30 12:10:21',
 '2016-01-30 12:10:42',
 '2016-01-30 12:11:03',
 '2016-01-30 12:11:24',
 '2016-01-30 12:11:45',
 '2016-01-30 12:12:06',
 '2016-01-30 12:12:27',
 '2016-01-30 12:12:48',
 '2016-01-30 12:13:10',
 '2016-01-30 12:13:31',
 '2016-01-30 12:13:52',
 '2016-01-30 12:14:13',
 '2016-01-30 12:14:34',
 '2016-01-30 12:14:55',
 '2016-01-30 12:15:16',
 '2016-01-30 12:15:37',
 '2016-01-30 12:15:59',
 '2016-01-30 12:16:20',
 '2016-01-30 12:16:41',
 '2016-01-30 12:17:02',
 '2016-01-30 12:17:23',
 '2016-01-30 12:17:44',
 '2016-01-30 12:18:05',
 '2016-01-30 12:18:26',
 '2016-01-30 12:18:48',
 '2016-01-30 12:19:09',
 '2016-01-30 12:19:30',
 '2016-01-30 12:19:51',
 '2016-01-30 12:20:12',
 '2016-01-30 12:20:33',
 '2016-01-30 12:20:54',
 '2016-01-30 12:21:15',
 '2016-01-30 12:21:36',
 '2016-01-30 12:21:58',
 '2016-01-30 12:22:19',
 '2016-01-30 12:22:40',
 '2016-01-30 12:23:01',
 '2016-01-30 12:23:22',
 '2016-01-30 12:23:35',
 '2016-01-30 12:24:14',
 '2016-01-30 12:24:25',
 '2016-01-30 12:24:51',
 '2016-01-30 12:25:00',
 '2016-01-30 12:25:29',
 '2016-01-30 12:25:50',
 '2016-01-30 12:26:11',
 '2016-01-30 12:26:32',
 '2016-01-30 12:26:49',
 '2016-01-30 12:27:14',
 '2016-01-30 12:27:36']
```

However, if you want to resample your data associated with those time-stamps, it might be better to leave it as a `pd.Series` and skip the last step. In the end you probably want to use [`pd.DataFrame.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), anyways.

Comment: Thanks @Graipher!! this is exactly what I was looking for. The trick with replacing the original measurements with the entry with smallest absolute difference is where I was really stuck. Thanks a lot! I will resample the associated data points with using the average speed of the vehicle.

Comment: @Kwadwo Be aware, though, that it might not work in some edge cases (i.e. one index being replaced by two values or something like that).